# Sending a js model in json or url encoded format?

Tags: javascript, http, backbone.js, request

Some js frameworks (e.g. [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON).js) send model data in json format by default. Is there any pros for that? At least in PHP post and get parameters are more easily accessible in comparison with json request body.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoded data only defines a mechanism for encoding key=value string pairs. (PHP extends that to support nested data structures, but not in a backend technology agnostic way).

JSON supports arrays, objects, strings, numbers, booleans and null.

Comment: But model data are generally came from HTML forms in which there is only a single datatype: string

Comment: If you're writing an application complicated enough to need something like Backbone, you'll usually have put the data in a more complex data structure on the client first.